# Vue.js component not getting the value from a variable

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm new to Vue.js and in my laravel app Im using this component https://github.com/saintplay/vue-swatches is working fine the problem is that I have an edit form and I want to pass the value (color in HEX) from a variable to the component as a selected like `value="{{$var->hex_color}}`.

This is my app.js

```
const d_app = new Vue({
 el:'#d_app',
 components: { 
  Swatches,
 },
 data:{
  color:'#ffffff',
 },
});
```

This is my form

```
<swatches v-model="color" colors="text-advanced" value="{{$var->hex_color}}"></swatches>
```

When I load the page it shows the default color `#ffffff` instead of the `$var->hex_color`.

Answer (score 0):

To pass value from Laravel to Vue component, encode it first.

Laravel:

```
<swatches :value="{{ json_encode($var->hex_color) }}"></swatches>
```

notice **":"** on the property name.
Now, let's accept that with Vue.

```
...
export default {
   props: ['value']
}
...
```

Now, you should be able to print the prop value:

```
<p>{{ value }}</p>

console.log(this.value) // Your hexa value passed from Laravel.
```

Comment: Sorry where I put the second step??

Comment: Second step is your Vue component.

Answer (score 0):

You have v-model indicated which already means that you are passing "value" to it and on change it should emit "input" event

```
<swatches v-model="color" colors="text-advanced" value="{{$var->hex_color}}"></swatches>
```

That's where the default #ffffff color is coming from, I suppose.

I think, if you remove v-model from there and leave only :value like this:

```
<swatches colors="text-advanced" :value="{{$var->hex_color}}"></swatches>
```

It might work. Have you tried it?

Or you can pass color to v-model directly:

```
<swatches colors="text-advanced" v-model="{{$var->hex_color}}"></swatches>
```

Comment: Tried both solutions shows `[Vue warn]: Error compiling template:` and the page doesn't load.

Comment: If I delete `v-model="colors"` and put `value="{{$var->hex_color}}"` works, but don't change if you chose another color.